# como puedo obtener un efecto tipo pinceladas en una imagen sea en python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Este es mi código en python, en la primera imagen es el resultado que obtengo, lo que necesito es saber como puedo obtener el resultado de la segunda imagen.

```
src = cv2.imread(os.getcwd() + os.sep + "result.jpg")
    scale_percent = 50
    width = int(src.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(src.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dsize = (width, height)
    imagen = cv2.resize(src, dsize)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(imagen, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 9)
    edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 9, 9)

    color = cv2.bilateralFilter(imagen, 9, 300, 300)
    cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(imagen, imagen, mask=edges)

    cv2.imshow("original", src)
    cv2.imshow("cartoon", cartoon)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Este es mi resultado]

[image: Este es el resultado que busco]

Comment: Una pregunta que pide lo mismo para diversos lenguajes es considerada demasiado amplia por lo que por ello he eliminado lo relevante a PHP. Si quieres la misma funcionalidad escrita en n lenguajes entonces debes crear n preguntas.

Comment: excelente comprendido, muchas gracias por la aclaracion, no volvera a suceder.